# Time goes slower the faster you go. What happens to time if you go too SLOW?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

Time dilation is clear about what happens when *Bob* goes faster than an Earth observer *Alice*, and about what happens when *Bob* travels at *speeds approaching* ***c*** with respect to Alice. From an observer on Earth (Alice), *Bob's time is going very slowly. But as Alice alternatively sees it, Alice's time is going much faster than Bob's*. But Earth is also moving, and thus we humans are not at the slowest speed. Someone, *Frank*, could be going slower than *Alice, and thus faster to Bob, and therefore to Bob (as Alice sees it) Frank's time compared to Alice's time would be going slower. That is, Alice's clocks would be going faster than Frank's clocks as Alice perceives Bob would see it.* Yet, there is a tendency to see time *in another framework* from only our inertial reference, and to say 'their time is going slower than our time' *instead of 'our time is going faster than their time'.*

*But let's look at it from a third framework.*

So, if Frank goes slower than Alice, then to Bob, Frank would be going faster. Alice's time would go faster for Bob than Frank's time would. (Or, perhaps more accurately, Frank's time would appear slower to Bob than Alice's time to Bob.)  Is there a limit on how FAST time can go, compared to another perspective? *That is, if Alice looks at both her and Frank's clocks as Bob would see them from her perspective, Alice's clocks go faster than Frank's. But how much faster? Could Alice look from Bob's perspective as Alice sees it and say 'My clocks are going infinitely faster than Frank's clocks, from Bob's framework, as I see it?* If ***c*** is the lower (zero) limit that produces the slowest (stationary) time, what is the fastest time an observer could observe their time as, compared to a second framework, from their perspective of looking at a third framework?

Comment: Going "slower" than us is just going *faster* in a different direction.

Comment: what happens can be measured using your own clock, can it not

Comment: @ACuriousMind Precisely my statement referencing 'more accurately, our time would appear slower to them'. But HOW much slower could this difference be, compared to YOUR inertial reference?

Comment: I assume that you are asking whether or not some people still see time in an early religious type of manner.  Once, from a religious Geocentric point of view, it was Earth that was considered to be at the center of the universe, the center of space. So I am assuming that you are asking whether or not some people say that time can tick no faster than here on Earth. Meaning, that once again, people still think that Earth is the master of time.

Comment: @Sean You are beginning to see my point, my question. I am asking exactly the opposite of what you claim. I am asking if some people can say that time on earth is ticking FASTER than here on earth? If so, then HOW MUCH faster? I am NOT assuming an earth-centric point of view. Is time ALWAYS slower somewhere else, for everyone, and never faster? Yet to the ISS crew, and the GPS satellites, time IS faster on earth, when speed is considered (not the gravitational effects.) whether on earth or the satellite. [link](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~pogge/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html)

Answer (score 8):

Time dilation is by no means clear about the thing that you think it's clear about: suppose Alice and Bob are in spaceships somewhere very far away from Earth, and those spaceships have a relative velocity approaching $c$. Then the following is true: Alice sees Bob's clocks ticking slowly, and also Bob sees Alice's clocks ticking slowly. This prevents a unilateral characterization of "Bob is moving fast, therefore his clocks are ticking slowly" -- the whole *point* of relativity is that these judgments become *relative*, and need to be analyzed as such.

The fastest any clock can possibly be ticking in a reference frame is in the reference frame which sees it at rest. In this frame of reference, its time will tick at a flat rate of one second per second. There is no bound on the slowest it can be seen to tick.

Comment: How does the twins paradox work? If I am getting older at regular 'rate' (1tick/s) and my twin traveling at speed v (<c) is also getting older at the same 'rate' both should of us should get older at the same rate?