What effect would relativity have for an objective with absolutely no momentum?
I know as you near the speed of light time slows down and mass increases to near infinite.  What I'm curious about is what would happen if an object lost all momentum.  No movement at all not even the expansion of the universe. Would time speed up and mass reach near zero?

Stand very still.   Do you feel weightless?

I can't stand very still.  The earth is spinning  and going around the sun. The sun if flying through the galaxy.  The galaxy is trekking through the cosmos. Even the universe itself is rushing outward as it expands so it seems. How will me standing very still help?

You can board a train, or a plane or a rocket ship, on earth or on the moon or anywhere you choose.   In your own (instantaneous) frame, your momentum is always zero.

"mass increases to near infinite" Velocity does not change an object's mass.

Similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355084/174766

Momentum is relative, not absolute. Relative to a passenger on the train, the train's momentum is zero. Relative to someone on the ground it is very large. So your question doesn't make sense, it seems to assume some kind of absolute motion, which is the opposite of relativity.

Momentum is actually truly relative. Neither mass nor velocity is absolute. Well, time slows and mass increases due to the lorentz transformation, (A part of General Relativity). As v tends to c, the lorentz factor increases.
What you say is actually contradictory. Mass doesn't become zero at rest, then the only option is ZERO velocity. But absolute zero velocity is impossible from all frames of reference.. So what do you mean? Do you imagine absolute rest? Even at rest, you won't have time speeding up and mass as zero, because the they don't scale up or down at rest the way you imagine it to be.

Zero velocity is impossible? Right now im lying in bed and can assure you that my velocity is zero, from my frame.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@GabrielYbarraMarcaida Ah i get what u mean
